# AJAX getting truncated on paragraph

Tags: ajax

I'm having a strange problem when trying to updated a div with a couple of paragrahs of text from AJAX.

Here are functions I'm using:

```
            var receivePapers = getXmlHttpRequestObject();
        function get_papers(myCat){
            if (receivePapers.readyState == 4 || receivePapers.readyState == 0) {
                receivePapers.open("GET", 'http://server/path/tocode/file.php?get_papers=1&student_id=1&category=' + myCat, true);
                receivePapers.onreadystatechange = handlereceivePapers;
                receivePapers.send(null);
            }
        }

        function handlereceivePapers() {
            if (receivePapers.readyState == 4) {
                var container_div = document.getElementById('paper_container');
                var xmldoc = receivePapers.responseXML;
                var paper_nodes = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("paper");
                var n_papers = paper_nodes.length;
                // Clear the whole container div.
                container_div.innerHTML = "";
                container_div.innerHTML = "<table class='categoryHeader' width='100%'><tr><th class ='categoryHeader' width='80%' ><br/>&nbsp;" + paper_nodes[1].getElementsByTagName("category")[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</br>&nbsp;<br/><br/></th></tr>";
                container_div.innerHTML += "<tr><td>";
                for (i = 0; i < n_papers; i++) {
                    var paper_id = paper_nodes[i].getElementsByTagName("paper_id");
                    var paper_title = paper_nodes[i].getElementsByTagName("paper_title");
                    var paper_desc = paper_nodes[i].getElementsByTagName("paper_desc");
                    var paper_time = paper_nodes[i].getElementsByTagName("paper_time");
                    var user_real_name = paper_nodes[i].getElementsByTagName("user_real_name");
                    var summary_div = document.createElement('div');
                    summary_div.innerHTML += "<table class='paper'><tr><td class='paperLike' width=80px rowspan=2 valign='top'><div id='" + paper_id[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "'><a href='#' onclick=\"vote('" + paper_id[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "'); event.returnValue=false; return false;\"> <img src='images/Like.png' style='padding-top:5px' border='0' /></a></div></td><td><table width='100%'><tr><td class='paperTitle' style='background-color:white; text-align=left; '><a class='paperTitle' style='padding-left:0;' href='#" + paper_id[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "'>" + paper_title[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</a></td><td class='paperName' style='margin-right:0; width:200px; background-color:white; text-align:right; vertical-align:text-top;'><span align='right' style='background-color:white; text-align:right; vertical-align:text-top; ' > " + user_real_name[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</span></td></tr></table></td><td rowspan='2' class='paperLength' style='width:80px; text-align:right; padding-top:8px;' >" + paper_time[0].firstChild.nodeValue +  " minutes</td></tr><tr><td class='paperDescription' align='left' colspan='1'>" + paper_desc[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td></tr></table>";
                    container_div.appendChild(summary_div);
                }
                container_div.innerHTML += "</tr></td></table";
            }
        }
```

Here is the XML that's getting returned:

```
<root>
<paper id="23">
    <paper_id>23</paper_id>
    <paper_title>title</paper_title>
    <paper_desc>
        First paragraph of desc
        <br/>
        <br/>
        Second paragraph of desc
        <br/>
        <br/>
        Third paragraph of desc
        <br/>
    </paper_desc>
    <paper_time>45</paper_time>
    <user_real_name>Bob Student</user_real_name>
    <user_id>2322</user_id>
    <category>Languages</category>
</paper>
...
```

When I push the content to container_div only the first paragraph is showing up.  If I stick a Javascript alert() in to return paper_desc it only contains the first paragraph.  I've tried looking for other nodes but this says there's only 1 node:

```
alert(paper_nodes[i].getElementsByTagName("paper_desc").length);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use paper_desc[0].firstChild.nodeValue

paper_desc[0] is a set of nodes: text nodes and br nodes. You get only the first child of this set, so you get only the first text.

Your alert() call only shows you have only one paper_desc node, not how many nodes you have inside.

I also found strange that you used paper_nodes[1] but I don't know if there is a second node in your XML and if you really want to target it.

Comment: That's what I'm using where I use the actual value in  "summary_div.innerHTML +=" ... it looks like this: 
<td class='paperDescription' align='left' colspan='1'>" + paper_desc[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>

I think I know what you mean by "paper_desc[0] is a set of nodes: text nodes and br nodes" but paper_nodes[i].getElementsByTagName("paper_desc").length says there's only one?

Or did I misunderstand?

In the place where I used paper_nodes[1] I was cheating a bit.  All nodes come from the same category so I just grab the category from the first node to create the category header.

Comment: Ok, after reading through my code again it turns out, of course, that you were right.  There are actually 7 childNodes under paper_desc (for text and br's).  Is there a quick/easy way to join all childnodes of paper_desc into a single value or do I have to iterate through them all?

Comment: In the end I just wrapped that paper_desc content in <![CDATA[ .. ]]> and things worked perfectly.  Your indication that there were more nodes under paper_dec[i] that I was missing led to this.  Thanks for that.